# How to find the date of next given name of the day in node.js

Tags: node.js, date

I have to find the date of the next given day in node.js.

Consider date as `2016-07-13(wednesday)`, I have to find the date of next given day(ex `monday, tuesday`,etc)

Suppose consider its `monday` it should be `2016-07-18`.

**EDIT:**

Consider date 2016-07-13, based on this date what is the nearest monday(desired) date.

**EDIT**

```
var target;
        if(desiredIndex < moment(start).day()){
            target = moment(start).day(7 + desiredIndex).toDate()
        } else {
            target = moment(start).day(desiredIndex).toDate();
        }
```

Answer (score 1):

I would use [moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and use `.day()` to set the target day of week as below. Add 7 to force "next week" semantics.

```
const moment = require('moment')
const dayOfWeekIndex = [
  'sunday',
  'monday',
  'tuesday',
  'wednesday',
  'thursday',
  'friday',
  'saturday']
const start = '2016-07-13'
const desired = 'tuesday' // change to suit taste.
const desiredIndex = dayOfWeekIndex.indexOf(desired)
// 7 means "next week"
const target = moment(start).day(7 + desiredIndex).toDate()
console.log(target)
```

Comment: Thanks..But consider date as wednesday(2016-07-13) and the desired day as monday it should return 2016-07-18(next week date). In the above code it will work for the scenario??

Comment: Based on current date its returning.. Its possible to return based on any date..Please see my edited post..

Comment: Yes I updated the code accordingly. You can pass a date or date string to `moment()` to initialize to something other than "now".

Comment: Still my requirement is not fulfilled.. Suppose consider 1.start 2016-07-13(wednesday) and the desired is monday(should return the next week monday's date).2. start 2016-07-13(wednesday) and the desired is thursday(which fall is same week) so it should return this week's thursday date. But if is add 7 for every then it will next week date for all... I think i explained clearly. i am ready to give input if needed..

Comment: please see my edited post. Now i am checking for whether the desired is falling on next or not?? Suggest me whether it will work for all scenarios??

Answer (score 0):

What I would do is use [Moment.js](http://momentjs.com/) and use the `moment.add(1, 'days').calendar();` operation.

The way I would do it, inside a function is saving the result into a date object, adding one by one in a for loop until your object contains the desired week day you trying to get, then you return that date.

Comment: Also for loop?? for which data i have to loop?